# How can I control the React-Bootstrap Dropdown visibility without a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I would like to pass a `show` prop or something similar to the dropdown and show accordingly.

```
          <Dropdown
            show={show}
              id="dropdown-basic-button"
              title="Dropdown button"
            >
              <Dropdown.Menu
                show={show}
              >
                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
              </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
```

The idea is that when the state changes, I would be able to show or hide the dropdown and change its items.

If I pass a boolean, it appears in the DOM but the `opacity` is `0`, therefore,
[it doesn't show up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxvMG.png)

[When I disable these attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf9si.png) the dropdown shows up.

Note: when I used the default way (with a button), it works.

Thanks for the help beforehand.

Comment: Do you want to show it always as open? How do you control it currently? Can you put it in  sandbox?

Comment: I would like to have control over the dropdown visibility (show/hide). My main idea is to have a condition in the parent component that when it's `true`, I will show the dropdown, if `false`, it will stay hidden.

According to the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/#examples), this is done via a toggle button but I'd like to control it via prop.

I will try to make a sandbox for that.

Comment: [Here is the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-control-visibility-example-7tp23). As you can see, I would like to show the dropdown only if the input has some text in it. This logic works for components like Popovers and Modals